where are the save all,save,print,new and other icons in visual basic 2010 express for applications
I created a program and wanted to add icons that I like. They are in toolstrip visual basic 2010 express, I dug through the vb resources and found icons, but there is no print, save all (these are the most important for me). Please tell me where I can download them, find them or something else
I mostly found .bmp files, but as I said above I didn't find the ones I wanted

This is somewhat vague.
You are not being specific regarding what Application are you referring too, what framework or language being used, etc.
I would recommend focusing on the framework being used to understand how you can incorporate an icon. After that, there are plenty of libraries with common icons available.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't know if there are any images in the old VB 2010 tool. But you can download the latest Visual Studio 2022 Image Library.

The Visual Studio 2022 image library includes legacy images (from previous versions including VS2012, VS2013, VS2015, VS2017 and VS2022), new images for 2022, and source files in vector format (e.g. SVG and XAMLfiles). The readme files include information about how to use these images appropriately in your applications and more details on the concepts.
To access the files in the image library, download Visual Studio 2022 Image Library.zip and extract the folders and images from the zip file.

